# From extending from AndroidApplication to Game

Tags: android, libgdx

When you start a project with libgdx it automatically makes the class extend Android Application. I did not think about this until later and now I want to change it to the Game and Screen classes. But unfortunately without success...

My first question is, how to I change the android project?

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;

public class AndroidClass extends AndroidApplication {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.useGL20 = false;

        initialize(new SplashScreen(), cfg);
    }
}
```

My second question: How do I change the deskop project:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;

public class DeskopClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.title = "MyApp";
        cfg.useGL20 = false;
        cfg.width = 800;
        cfg.height = 480;

        new LwjglApplication(new SplashScreen(), cfg);
    }
}
```

Third question: How do I change the SplashScreen:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class SplashScreen implements ApplicationListener{

    @Override
    public void create() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: You might benefit from reading the "Manual Project Setup" portion of the wiki: http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ProjectSetup  Maybe even give the "Simple App" section a once over: http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/SimpleApp

Comment: There is nothing there that answering my queston, but thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Game](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/Game.java) class is just an `ApplicationListener`.  `AndroidApplication` and `Game` are not interchangeable classes as they accomplish two different things.

You need an `AndroidApplication` class to pass events on to your `ApplicationListener` classes.  If you want a `Game` class in your app then you can always create your own.

```
public class Game implements ApplicationListener {

    @Override
    public void dispose () {

    }

    @Override
    public void pause () {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume () {

    }

    @Override
    public void render () {

    }

    @Override
    public void resize (int width, int height) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But how can I use the setScreen() method if i make my own game class?

Comment: See the link to the `Game` class in my answer.  That has the entire class.  I was just giving an example blank implementation here.

Comment: You can just extend the existing class if you want.  Once again, I was just giving a sample `ApplicationListener` implementation.

Comment: Yeah, and that's what I'm trying to do! But I always getting errors like ClassCastException: *CLASS* cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Comment: That's because your `AndroidApplication` class CANNOT be a `Game` as well.  Your `AndroidApplication` is there to drive the `Game` class or any other `ApplicationListener` class you create.

Comment: Oh I get it! Thank alot again MCeley, you are the greatest!

Comment: Not a problem sir.  Just remember that the project wiki is your friend.  You can also look at the GitHub page for libgdx as it also has a lot of good information. https://github.com/libgdx

Answer (score 0):

Game class in libgdx is itself an ApplicationListener.

You can create a class that extends Game and directly pass its object to initialize (for android) and LwjglApplication (for desktop).
This way you can use setScreen without a problem.